# Java: Display the complete set of unique values input after the user enters each new value

Tags: java

I need to write a code that "Display the complete set of unique values input after the user enters each new value." Such as:

The·complete·set·of·unique·values·entered·is:↵

Unique·Value·1:·is·100↵

Unique·Value·2:·is·10↵

Unique·Value·3:·is·20↵

I have attached my code below, and have the code completed, however, it seems to come across errors on my very last line to produce the last "this is the first time (user input) has been entered" & the unique value portion results of Unique Value # is (user input that's unique and stored in array). There seems to be an error in the very last System.out.println("Unique...) line.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
 public class DisplayUniqueValueInput {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       // creating an ArrayList from user input
       ArrayList<Integer> userInputs = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);

       // prompt user and store input   
       int count = 0;     
       while (true) {
           int a = 0;
           while(true) {
               System.out.print("Enter an integer between 10 and 100:");
               a = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
               if (a < 10 || a > 100)
                  System.out.println("Invalid input\n");
               else
                  break;
           }  
           count++;
           if (count == 5)
              break;
           boolean ifExists = false;             
           for(int i = 0; i<userInputs.size(); i++) {
              if (userInputs.get(i) == a) {
                 ifExists = true;
                 break;

              }
           }
           if (!ifExists){
              System.out.printf("This is the first time %d has been entered\n", a);
              userInputs.add(a);
           }      
       } // end while statement

    // output unique values
       System.out.println("\nThe complete set of unique values entered is:\n");
       for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
           System.out.println("Unique Value" + userInputs[i] + "is:" + " ");
       }
   } // end main method
} // end of class
```

Comment: Why don’t you just use arraylist.size() to track the size? And what’s the error specifically?

Comment: I added the userInputs.size();  and this is my output: Enter an integer between 10 and 100:10
This is the first time 10 has been entered
Enter an integer between 10 and 100:10
Enter an integer between 10 and 100:20
This is the first time 20 has been entered
Enter an integer between 10 and 100:30
This is the first time 30 has been entered
Enter an integer between 10 and 100:40

The complete set of unique values entered is:

Unique Value3is:

Comment: sorry, it does not seem to be formatting correctly, but the last input still does not post "this is the first time (unique value) has been entered" and the unique value now just states 3 and produces no unique value list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little off-topic but if you must store unique elements, you normally go for a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). That being said, in the portion of the code where you collect the user input, you are asking for `5` numbers but storing `4` e.g.:

```
   int count = 0;     
   while (true) {
       int a = 0;
       while(true) {
           System.out.print("Enter an integer between 10 and 100:");
           a = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
           if (a < 10 || a > 100)
              System.out.println("Invalid input\n");
           else
              break;
       }  
       // count++;
       // if (count == 5) if you break here, the code below won't be reached
       //   break;        thus you will never store the last user input 

       // Lists have a method contains that does exactly what you are trying to do
       // Consider using ifExists = userInput.contains(a)
       boolean ifExists = false;             
       for(int i = 0; i<userInputs.size(); i++) {
          if (userInputs.get(i) == a) {
             ifExists = true;
             break;

          }
       }
       if (!ifExists){
          System.out.printf("This is the first time %d has been entered\n", a);
          userInputs.add(a);
       }      
        // consider breaking here after you have collected the last user input
        // alternatively, use a do{ ... } while(); loop
        count++;
        if (count == 5)
            break;
   } // end while statement
```

You are not printing the iteration variable `i` e.g.:

```
// output unique values
System.out.println("\nThe complete set of unique values entered is:\n");
for(int i = 0; i < userInputs.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println("Unique Value " + (i + 1) + ": is " + userInputs.get(i));
}
```

Also as mentioned in another answer, in your `for-loop` the variable `i` must go up to `< userInputs.size()` since if you try to go up to `5`, it will break if the user entered duplicate values.

Comment: Thank you! This works, however, it does not seem to include the 5th input if that input is unique.

Comment: Oh my goodness! Thank you so much! I have finally solved this problem and your suggestions ABSOLUTELY helped!!!!!!!! :D

Comment: @NoblestArgon glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

For the last loop, you should do this instead, because your array is to store unique numbers, right? So if there is less than 5 unique number, your program will break, and why don't use Set instead?

```
// output unique values
    System.out.println("\nThe complete set of unique values entered is:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < userInputs.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Unique Value" + userInputs.get(i) + "is:" + " ");
    }
```

Comment: This is absolutely on the right track. With an input of 10, 10, 20, 30, 40, this outputs: The complete set of unique values entered is:

Unique Value10is: 
Unique Value20is: 
Unique Value30is:

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because in the last `for` loop you try to access your list with `userInputs[i]` instead of `userInputs.get(i)`

Comment: adding in:System.out.println("Unique Value " + userInputs.size() + " is:" + userInputs.get(i)); With an input of 10,10,20,30,40    Produces: Unique Value 3is:10        
Unique Value 3is:20          
Unique Value 3is:30

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accept and print only unique value, Perhaps use `Set` instead of `ArrayList`. Example:-

```
public static void main(String args[]){

     Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<>();         

     for(String input : args){

         Integer num = Integer.parseInt(input);
         if(!(numbers.add(num))){
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number already have");
         }
         System.out.println("Unique number =" + num);
     }
}
```

A `Set` is a collection that contains no duplicate elements. Refer to its [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) for details.

** *Sample above just for brevity, you may retrofit your program with `Set` type*.